# Data not ingested into the table from GCS to Bigquery using Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-storage

I am running a DAG in airflow, where the data is supposed to be ingested into BQ table from GCS bucket that consists of csv files.

When I ran the DAG in Airflow, the DAG is mentioning that the data in files is successfully ingested from GCS to Bigquery even mentioning the files that are processed.

But when I check the table, the data is not actually present in it

I have gone through the Bigquery jobs. The jobs pertaining to this ingestion mention that data is ingested into the BQ table.

But when I check the table, the data is not actually present in it

What might be the issue for data to be absent in the table?

PS:

1. The last modified timestamp in the Bigquery table is near the end timestamp of Airflow DAG
2. I ran this DAG earlier and the DAG ingested the data from few files into the table. That data is present in the table